# angular emoji not working on ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to load these scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
```

in ionic framework to load/render emoticons using emoji.min.js
The emoticons renders very well when I build a separate app not on ionic to demo it. But immediately I integrate it into ionic app, it freezes.
This is the github url for the project
https://github.com/sagardalal21/AngularEmoji-IonicApp
To run the project, kindly open command prompt and type `ionic serve`
Kindly assist!

Answer (score 0):

## EMOJIS IN ANGULAR AND IONIC [by pookdeveloper](https://github.com/pookdeveloper/)

[EMOJIS IN ANGULAR AND IONIC](https://github.com/pookdeveloper/emojis-angular-ionic)

### To show emjois in angular or ionic you can try this:

- Create a service to call a json with all emojis, you can finde the emojis in this page: 
  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dzfweb/nativescript-emoji/master/emoji.database.ts

```typescript
emojis(): any {
    return this.http.get('assets/data/emoji.json')
        .map((res: any) => res.json());
}
```

- Call the service:

```typescript
/* CALL SERVICE TO GET EMOJIS */
emoticonos() {
  this.confData.emojis().subscribe((data: any) => {
    console.log("EMOJIS", data);
    this.emojis = data;
  });
}
```

- Print the emojis:

```html
<ion-item-group *ngFor="let emoji of emojis">
    {{emoji.unicode}}
</ion-item-group>
```